# Cutting body and pagan tattoos forbidden in Leviticus 19, what pagan group?

Tags: leviticus

There is a curious law in Leviticus that seems to refer to avoiding an ancient pagan rite.

> Do not cut your bodies for the dead or put tattoo marks on yourselves. I am the Lord. (Leviticus 19:28

[Mathew Henry](http://m.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/matthew-henry-complete/) says:

> They must not make cuts or prints in their flesh for the dead; for the heathen did so to pacify the infernal deities they dreamt of, and to render them propitious to their deceased friends.

My question is does anyone know of any secular source, or have an internal exegesis, that would either verify this claim or cast an alternate theory?

Comment: Not an answer but I'm just hoping to toss some info in for anyone who may be answering ... `Ketovet Ka'aka` is a *hapax legomenon* (only occurs once).

Comment: "it is indicated that cutting oneself is wrong." *for the priests*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[John Gill](http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/gills-exposition-of-the-bible/leviticus-19-28.html) uses these sources:

> **Jarchi** says, it was the custom of the Amorites, when anyone died, to
> cut their flesh, as it was of the Scythians, as Herodotus relates,
> even those of the royal family; for a king they cut off a part of the
> ear, shaved the hair round about, cut the arms about, wounded the
> forehead and nose, and transfixed the left hand with arrows; and so
> the Carthaginians, who might receive it from the Phoenicians, being a
> colony of theirs, used to tear their hair and mouths in mourning, and
> beat their breasts; and with the Romans the women used to tear
> their cheeks in such a manner that it was forbid by the law of the
> twelve tables, which some have thought was taken from hence: and all
> this was done to appease the infernal deities, and to give them
> satisfaction for the deceased, and to make them propitious to them, as
> **Varro** affirms; and here it is said to be made "for the soul", for
> the soul of the departed, to the honour of it, and for its good,
> though the word is often used for a dead body: now, according to the
> Jewish canons, whosoever made but one cutting for a dead person was
> guilty, and to be scourged; and he that made one for five dead men, or
> five cuttings for one dead man, was obliged to scourging for everyone
> of them: nor print any marks upon you; **Aben Ezra** observes, there are
> some that say this is in connection with the preceding clause, for
> there were who marked their bodies with a known figure, by burning,
> for the dead; and he adds, and there are to this day such, who are
> marked in their youth in their faces, that they may be known; these
> prints or marks were made with ink or black lead, or, however, the
> incisions in the flesh were filled up therewith; but this was usually
> done as an idolatrous practice; so says **Ben Gersom**, this was the
> custom of the Gentiles in ancient times, to imprint upon themselves
> the mark of an idol, to show that they were his servants.

You may trace the links through the reference.

Answer (score 5):

While not a "secular source", there is a reference in [1 Kings 18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%2018:20-40&version=NASB) to false prophets cutting themselves in the "showdown" between the prophets of Baal and Elijah.

[v28](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%2018:28&version=NASB):

> So they cried with a loud voice and cut themselves according to their custom with swords and lances until the blood gushed out on them.

Also, in [Leviticus 21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2021&version=NASB), in the descriptions of the Lord's priests:

> They shall not make any baldness on their heads, nor shave off the edges of their beards, nor make any cuts in their flesh.

it is indicated that cutting oneself is wrong.

Comment: Good reminder about 1 Kings. I will wait a couple days for a secular source, and if nothing shows up I will accept this answer. Cheers.